# How to get all key combinations after groupby in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I would like to have all combination of keys after a groupby so if `a` has `na` unique values and `b` has `nb` unique values than the number of output rows should be `na*nb`. I have tried `reindex` and `reindex_axis` but it didn't work:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,2,3],'b':[1, 2, 3,4], 'c':[1,2,3,4]})
>>> df.groupby(['a','b']).count()
     c
a b  
1 1  1
  2  1
2 3  1
3 4  1
```

I would like to get:

```
a b  
1 1  1
  2  1
  3  None
  4  None
2 1  None
  2  None
  3  1
  4  None
3 1  None
  2  None
  3  None
  4  1
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use reindex:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df['a'].unique(), df['b'].unique()))
df.groupby(['a','b']).count().reindex(idx)

Out: 
       c
1 1  1.0
  2  1.0
  3  NaN
  4  NaN
2 1  NaN
  2  NaN
  3  1.0
  4  NaN
3 1  NaN
  2  NaN
  3  NaN
  4  1.0
```

Comment: And with ``pd.MultiIndex.from_product(..., names=['a','b'])`` you can name the columns of the MultiIndex. Thanks for the great tip @ayhan!